# VBA Loop crashing excel every time

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a VBA code that follows instructions on each cell starting with cell E4. U means up, D means down and R means right. It will follow the directions and end at a cell 'Cottage'. However, the code crashed my excel every time I try to run it. By chasing - I mean excel just stops responding. Attaching a snippet of the sheet for further clarity - Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xQxE.png)

```
Sub findhome()
Range("E4").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "Cottage"
        If ActiveCell.Value = "R" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "D" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "U" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        End f
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: have you done any [debugging](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx)?  You can step through your code line by ine and see what's going wrong. Otherwise, please provide a [mcve] which includes example input data so that others may test and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I notice you have an infinite loop condition. If the selection lands on any cell which doesn't contain value R/D/U or Cottage, the loop will continue for infinity.

Comment: By "crashing" do you mean putting Excel in a "not responding" state? Judging by what you're doing, if you never find "Cottage", you'll never exit the loop.

Comment: Yes, I mean excel stops responding.

Comment: Attached an image of the relevant sheet/data source for further clarity.

Comment: There are cells containing all of the values - R/D/U and Cottage - so it should work.